# Approval Process Query

Tags: approval-process

In one of our approval requirements we would want the approvals to be submitted to a queue (containing 5 members).

We want the approval to be "Approved" only if any 2 members from that queue approve it.

Is this possible to implement without code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approval processes steps can have multiple approvers assigned, and have an option called `whenMultipleApprovers` that can be set to either:

- `Unanimous` - all approvers need to approve, or
- `FirstResponse` - approval or rejection based on the first approver's action.

There isn't an option for 2 members to approve an approval step.

Maybe you could consider making this a two-step approval process, with each step set to `FirstResponse`, and adding all 5 members to both steps in the approval process.